# Wordpress Page to use a template.php from a plugin directory

Tags: php, wordpress

First time building a plugin for `Wordpress`.

I add a page to my site programmatically like this in my plugin:

```
$page_check = get_page_by_title( $page_path );
$page = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_title' => $page_title,
    'post_content' => $page_content,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => $author->ID,
    'post_slug' => $page_path
);

if (!isset($page_check->ID) && !get_page_by_path($page_path)) {
    $page_id = wp_insert_post($page);
}
```

I want to make this specific page use the `campaigns.php` page template I have in my plugin folder (`/wp-content/my-plugin/campaigns.php`)

I understand I can update this page's metadata like this:

```
update_metadata( 'page',  $page_id, '_wp_page_template', 'your_custom_template' );
```

How do I point the `your_custom_template` piece to my `campaings.php`? Can this be done? Thanks.

UPDATE:

With help below I understand this should work:

```
// $template resolves correctly to the full path to the `php` file
$template = $settings->plugin_path . 'campaigns.php'; 
update_post_meta($page_id, '_wp_page_template', $template);
```

The plugin path / file:

```
$template = '/home/vagrant/src/wptest/wp-content/plugins/pm/campaigns.php';
```

But the page, on entering the edit screen, still points to default template. Selecting the template manually makes no difference to the page. What did I miss?

This is my basic `campaigns.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Campaigns
 *
 * @package PM
 */
?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">
            <section class="outer-categories">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row text-justify">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <?php
                            while ( have_posts() ) :
                                the_post();

                                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );

                            endwhile; // End of the loop.
                            ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
```

Comment: You can use page_template filter hook to assign to a particular template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [theme_page_templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/theme_page_templates/)

```
   function wpmodify_add_page_template ($templates) {
        $templates['my-custom-template.php'] = 'My Template';
        return $templates;
        }

    add_filter ('theme_page_templates', 'wpmodify_add_page_template');
```

Now Set the plugin path to template - See [page_template](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/page_template)

```
function wpmodify_redirect_page_template ($template) {
    if ('my-custom-template.php' == basename ($template))
        $template = WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/mypluginname/my-custom-template.php';
    return $template;
    }
add_filter ('page_template', 'wpmodify_redirect_page_template');
```

Comment: Hi Mujeebu, This adds the template to the list of templates you can select in the page editor. I do this to assign it to the page I add, but it fails.

        $template = $settings->plugin_path . 'campaign_page.php';
         update_post_meta($page_id, '_wp_page_template', $template );